# "Permissions are too open" while logging in to ssh

Tags: ssh, permissions, openssh

I have a problem while I am logging to my SSH server using OpenSSH (note: i am on windows and i need to use OpenSSH)

```
Permissions 0644 for 'privkey.ppk' are too open.
It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: privkey.ppk
Enter passphrase for key 'privkey.ppk':
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to convert the PPK file format to OpenSSH format, if you want to use it in SSH.

Second thing is that the private key should not be readable by anyone else but you. So setting permissions to `600` is a good idea (`chmod 600 privkey.ppk`).

Comment: As i said, I am on windows, and I don't know if there's a way you can do chmod on Windows, but thanks anyways.

Comment: Of course there is alternative on windows, but you will probably have to click on the file with right button of mouse and find some properties, but I have no idea how does it work.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the file permission to `400` not `600`.